# Identify if file exists

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to identify if a file exists, as part of an error handling process in Python 3.7.2. As part of the process I have tried to user `os.path.isfile()` however, I seem to be getting a syntax error on the if statement.

How do I go about fixing this, so that it reads correctly?

The code is:

```
import sys
import os
import random
import time

while True:
    try:
        user_input = input("Enter the path of your file (Remember to include the file name and extension): ")   # Imports user defined file

    if os.path.isfile(user_input) == False:
        print("I did not find the file at, "+str(user_input)                                                    # Checks if file is present
        continue

    else:
        break
```

Edit: to include error type

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: why are you using `try` without an `except` or `finally`?

Comment: Sorry, says syntax error on the 'if' statement. Will edit to include

Comment: No, not the "error type". What's the actual error message?

Comment: Error given as: SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
import sys
import os
import random
import time

while True:
    try:
        user_input = input("Enter the path of your file (Remember to include the file name and extension): ")   # Imports user defined file

        if os.path.isfile(user_input):
            print("I did not find the file at, "+str(user_input))                                                # Checks if file is present
            continue
        else:
            break
    except:
        print('Error')
```

However this much of code is not required...
This will be sufficient

```
import sys
import os
import random
import time
while True:
    user_input = input("Enter the path of your file (Remember to include the file name and extension): ")   # Imports user defined file
    if not os.path.isfile(user_input):
        print("I did not find the file at, "+str(user_input))
        continue
    else:
        # some functions
        break
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import os
from builtins import input

while True:
    user_input = input(
        "Enter the path of your file (Remember to include the file name and extension): ")

    if not os.path.isfile(user_input):
        print(f"I did not find the file at {user_input}")
        continue
    else:
        break
```

Answer (score 1):

At it's simplest, because I'm not sure why you needed a try statement:

```
import os

path = input("Enter the path of your file (Remember to include the file "
             "name and extension)")
if os.path.exists():
    pass
else:
    print("I did not find the file at, "+str(path))
```